Изменить раскладку визуальной клавиатуры
У меня есть класс Keyboard в котором рисуется клавиатура и класс KeyEvent, в котором визуализируется нажатие на клавиши. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на комбинацию alt + shift, поменялся язык на визуальной клавиатуре.
Пробовал полностью очищать клавиатуру, удаляя все элементы, но при вызове setupUI она не появляется.
interface
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy,
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from create_keyboard import Keyboard

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(750, 443)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.main_frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_frame.setObjectName(u"main_frame")
        self.main_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.main_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.main_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.Keyboard = Keyboard(self.main_frame)
        self.Keyboard.setObjectName(u"Keyboard")
        self.Keyboard.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Keyboard.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Keyboard)


    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.main_frame)

    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
# setupUi

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
# retranslateUi


class Test(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.installEventFilter(self.Keyboard.events)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv, exit
    app = QApplication(argv)
    window = Test()
    window.show()
    exit(app.exec())

create_keyboard.py
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem, QVBoxLayout
from key_events import KeyEvent


class Keyboard(QFrame):

    ru = ['', 'Ё', '1 !', '2 "', '3 №', '4 ;', '5 %', '6 :', '7 ?', '8 *', '9 (', '0 )', '- _', '= +', 'BackSpace', '',
        '', 'Tab', 'Й', 'Ц', 'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Г', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'З', 'Х', 'Ъ', '\\ /', '',
        '', 'Caps', 'Ф', 'Ы', 'В', 'А', 'П', 'Р', 'О', 'Л', 'Д', 'Ж', 'Э', 'Enter', '',
        '', 'Shift', 'Я', 'Ч', 'С', 'М', 'И', 'Т', 'Ь', 'Б', 'Ю', '. ,', 'LShift', '',
        '', 'Alt', 'Space', '']
    eng = ['', '` ~', '1 !', '2 @', '3 #', '4 $', '5 %', '6 ^', '7 &', '8 *', '9 (', '0 )', '- _', '= +', 'BackSpace', '',
        '', 'Tab', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '[ {', '] }', '\\ |', '',
        '', 'Caps', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', '; :', '\' "', 'Enter', '',
        '', 'Shift', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ', <', '. >', '/ ?', 'LShift', '',
        '', 'Alt', 'Space', '']
    symbols = '~!@#$%^&*()_+\\{}:"<>?!"№;%:?*()_+/,|'
    sizes = {'BackSpace': (100, 140), 'Tab': (80, 110), '\\ /': (70, 100),
         '\\ |': (70, 100), 'Caps': (100, 130), 'Enter': (100, 155),
         'Shift': (130, 170), 'LShift': (130, 190), 'Space': (400, 550)}

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 385))

        self.keys = None
        self.setupUI('ru')

        self.events = KeyEvent(self)

    def setupUI(self, lang):
        self.keys = self.ru if lang == 'ru' else self.eng
        lines = {'Line_1': self.keys[:16], 'Line_2': self.keys[16:32], 'Line_3': self.keys[32:47],
             'Line_4': self.keys[47:61], 'Line_5': self.keys[61:]}

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(5)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)

        for i, ln in enumerate(lines.keys()):
            line = QFrame(self)
            line.setObjectName(ln)

            horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(line)
            horizontalLayout.setSpacing(5)
            horizontalLayout.setObjectName(f"horizontalLayout_{i}")
            horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

            for key in lines[ln]:
                if not key:
                    horizontalSpacer = QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                    horizontalLayout.addItem(horizontalSpacer)
                    continue

                label = QLabel(line)
                if key[-1] in self.symbols:
                    label.setObjectName(f'Key_{key[0]}')
                else:
                    label.setObjectName(f'Key_{key}')
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                label.setText(key)
                if key in self.sizes.keys():
                    minimal, maximum = self.sizes[key]
                    label.setMinimumSize(QSize(minimal, 50))
                    label.setMaximumSize(QSize(maximum, 70))
                else:
                    label.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 50))
                    label.setMaximumSize(70, 70)
                label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                horizontalLayout.addWidget(label)

            for index, key in enumerate(lines[ln]):
                if key:
                    if (ln == 'Line_1' and index == 14 or ln == 'Line_2' and index in (1, 14)
                        or ln == 'Line_3' and index in (1, 13) or ln == 'Line_4' and index in (1, 12)):
                        horizontalLayout.setStretch(index, 3)

                    else:
                        horizontalLayout.setStretch(index, 1)

                    if ln == 'Line_5':
                        horizontalLayout.setStretch(0, 4)
                        horizontalLayout.setStretch(1, 1)
                        horizontalLayout.setStretch(2, 8)
                        horizontalLayout.setStretch(3, 4)

            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(line)

key_events.py
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QObject
from PySide6.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel
from ctypes import WinDLL


def _get_capslock_state():
    hllDll = WinDLL("User32.dll")
    VK_CAPITAL = 0x14
    return hllDll.GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) != 0


class KeyEvent(QObject):
    keys = {Qt.Key_Backspace: "BackSpace", Qt.Key_Return: "Enter", Qt.Key_Space: "Space",
            Qt.Key_Tab: "Tab", Qt.Key_Alt: "Alt"}

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.caps_on = _get_capslock_state()
        self.system_button = False

        if self.caps_on:
            self._search_button('Caps').setStyleSheet(u'background-color: #999999')

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if event.type() == QKeyEvent.KeyPress:
            key: QKeyEvent = event

            # Изменить клавиатуру здесь
            if key.modifiers() is Qt.AltModifier | Qt.ShiftModifier:
                pass

            if key.nativeScanCode() == 54:
                self._search_button('LShift').setStyleSheet(u'background-color: #999999')
            if key.nativeScanCode() == 42:
                self._search_button('Shift').setStyleSheet(u'background-color: #999999')

            for k, v in self.keys.items():
                if key.key() == k:
                    self._search_button(v).setStyleSheet(u'background-color: #999999')
                    self.system_button = True

            if key.key() == Qt.Key_CapsLock and not self.caps_on:
                self._search_button('Caps').setStyleSheet(u'background-color: #999999')
                self.caps_on = True
                return True
            elif key.key() == Qt.Key_CapsLock and self.caps_on:
                self._search_button('Caps').setStyleSheet(u'background-color: none')
                self.caps_on = False

            if not self.system_button:
                if key.modifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier and key.text():
                    self._search_button(self._translate(key.text())).setStyleSheet(u'background-color: #999999')

                if key.modifiers() == Qt.NoModifier and key.text():
                    self._search_button(key.text().upper()).setStyleSheet(u'background-color: #999999')

        if event.type() == QKeyEvent.KeyRelease:
            key: QKeyEvent = event

            if key.nativeScanCode() == 54:
                self._search_button('LShift').setStyleSheet(u'background-color: none')
            if key.nativeScanCode() == 42:
                self._search_button('Shift').setStyleSheet(u'background-color: none')

            for k, v in self.keys.items():
                if key.key() == k:
                    self._search_button(v).setStyleSheet(u'background-color: none')
                    self.system_button = False
                    return True

            if key.modifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier and key.text():
                self._search_button(self._translate(key.text())).setStyleSheet(u'background-color: none')

            if key.modifiers() == Qt.NoModifier and key.text():
                self._search_button(self._translate(key.text()).upper()).setStyleSheet(u'background-color: none')

        return super().eventFilter(watched, event)

    def _search_button(self, name):
        buttons = self.parent.findChildren(QLabel)
        for btn in buttons:
            name_button = btn.objectName().split('_')[1]
            if name_button == name:
                return btn

    def _translate(self, text):
        if self.parent.keys == self.parent.eng:
            maketrans = text.maketrans('~!@#$%^&*()_+|{}:"<>?', '`1234567890-=\\[];\',./')
        else:
            maketrans = text.maketrans('!"№;%:?*()_+/,', '1234567890-=\\.')
        return text.translate(maketrans)


Создал функцию которая удаляет всю клавиатуру и отрисовывает ее заново.
Так же переместил строку self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self) из stupUI() в инициализацию.
Теперь все прекрасно работает.
def change_layout(self):
    for i in self.findChildren(QFrame):
        i.setParent(None)
        del i

    self.switch = True
    self.setupUI()

